# My function returns a string but comparison is always wrong

Tags: javascript, php, return

I have a PHP function which returns true or false as a String (this works). If I look into my JS file I make an alert box with the responseText of the XMLHttprequest (this works as well). But as soon as I try to compare the responsestring to another string the outcome is always false.

I've already searched stackoverflow but did not find an answer. I also tried str.equals(""), as well as returning a boolean with php but nothing seemed to work.

Javascript:

```
xhttp.onload = function(){
    alert(xhttp.responseText); //Here comes "true" or "false" just like I want it
    if(xhttp.responseText == "true"){ //This always gives me "ERROR and then the responseText (which is true or false)
        alert("TRUE");
    }else if(xhttp.responseText == "false"){
        alert("FALSE");
    }else{
        alert("ERROR" + xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

PHP:

```
if(count($echo)==3){
            if($tag==$echo[2]){
                echo "true";
                break;
            }else if($i == (count($fahrten)-1)){
                echo "false";
            }
        }
```

Expected result: alert with "TRUE" or "FALSE"
actual result: alert with "Error" followed by the responseText

I hope some of you can help me and the question is not too stupid I'm stil learning an it is for a scholl project.

Comment: Have you debugged the PHP side of this issue? I.e.: have you just run the PHP script and looked at the output with different kinds of input? Looks like you depend on some variables in order to get it to output "true". If those conditions are not met, you'll get "false".

Comment: "this always gives me "ERROR ... " -> What is the error?

Comment: Possibly some extra whitespace in the response , trim it before comparing value

Comment: perhaps the data received is in a format by the script that always causes the `error` condition to run. Try trimming the data before passing it to the if-else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try trimming `responseText` before comparing:

```
xhttp.onload = function(){
    var responseText = xhttp.responseText.trim();

    alert(responseText); //Here comes "true" or "false" just like I want it
    if(responseText  == "true"){ //This always gives me "ERROR and then the responseText (which is true or false)
        alert("TRUE");
    }else if(responseText  == "false"){
        alert("FALSE");
    }else{
        alert("ERROR" + responseText );
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works :). But I can't acceptyour answer, it seems like I have to wait a bit, I'll try later :)

Answer (score 0):

Your xhttp.responseText == "true" comparison will always return false.. Instead, I would try simplifying your conditions:

```
xhttp.onload = function(){
    alert(xhttp.responseText);
    if (xhttp.responseText) {
        // true case
        alert("TRUE");
    }
    else {
        // false case
        alert("ERROR" + xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you put a break point in front of first if statement and see what xhttp actually looks like?